# How to pop self and then perform a segue from the parent view controller?

Tags: swift3, segue

[image]

I have a tableview view controller named `ItemsViewController` embedded in a navigation view controller that displays items .

Flow 1 (works as expected)
I have a 'New Item' button on the `ItemsViewController` which when clicked shows a view controller popup (`AddItemViewController`) where you can add the item's name and other details. When you click 'Save' the view is popped and the `ItemsViewController` is displayed showing the newly created item.

Flow 2
While creating a new item if you click 'Save and Open' I want it to pop the `AddItem view controller` and push the `itemDetail` view controller showing the newly created item's name and other item details.

So inside the AddItemsView controller's 'Save and open' action I have:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowItemList", sender: newItemList)
})
```

This dismisses the Itemsview controller but then it crashes with `thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

EDIT

If I refer to the parent it dismisses the add view controller but doesn't perform the segue

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
 self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowItemList", sender: newItemList)
})
```

Comment: Are you presenting `AddItemsView` or pushing the `AddItemsView` controller in navigation? Because if you are presenting then you need to use `dismiss` and if you pushing controller then you need to pop the controller but don't perform both the action.

Comment: Thanks for this. In the storyboard I created a Present as Popover segue

Comment: Welcome mate :) Is your problem solved?

Comment: It means you are getting nil somewhere, Add the code of `prepareforsegue` method of ItemViewController.

Comment: You haven't added `prepareForSegue` add that method so it will give idea us where you are getting nil. Also `self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowItemList", sender: newItemList)` is not working because in completion you probably getting nil for `self.parent?` and it is optional so there is no crash and no segue is performing.

Answer (score 0):

do following:

1) call dismiss method in addItemViewController

```
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.delegate.methodToCall()
```

you have to make delegate when you back from addItemViewController and implement method in parent class when you back from addItemViewController

2) Then in your itemsViewController immplement that method like

```
    func yourMethodToCall() {
          self.perform(#selector(ItemViewController.temp), with:nil, afterDelay: 0.4)

         }      

    func temp(){
    // push view controller here

       }
```